# How to add visual basic selected calender to SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net

i would like to ask, how can i add the selected date in my calender in to my SQL? I believe the format for SQL i got is `0000-00-00 while` in Visual basic is 
`StartDateCalender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString.`

How do i format it so it will be the same as the SQL format?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you are using the Date, please? Do you want to INSERT new data in to your database? Also, never convert a date to string just to store the date value in the database, it will cause you many problems, now and later on.

Comment: By using a parameter. Assign the date to the parameter, it should handle the storing properly in the table.

Comment: I got it sorted out! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

For dates/times you can easily format however you wish (within reason) by using `String.Format()`.

Some examples:

```
String.Format(yourDateFieldHere, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt')
String.Format(yourDateFieldHere, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
String.Format(yourDateFieldHere, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS')
String.Format(yourDateFieldHere, 'MM-dd-yyyy')
```